# WolfSSL: Resume Session failure due to configuration issue of build (cmake)

Tags: ssl, makefile, cmake, tls1.3, wolfssl

I am using an *Ubuntu 20.04* machine along with the *CLion IDE 2020.3.2* and I want to create an app using [WolfSSL](https://www.wolfssl.com/) which would need the TLS1.3 implementation of it.

Using CLion, I cloned the official repository https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl.git. CLion automatically built the project and I was able to run all the `\wolfssl\examples` perfectly.
Thus, the **resumption** session does not work.
I run both Server/Client with these arguments: `client/server -v 4 -r`
And I am getting this output from the client side: `didn't reuse session id!!!` which I can verify from Wireshark that there was no resumption made but just another handshake.

At another build I did, where instead of `cmake` ( which is the default of CLion ) I used `make` I manged to run properly the **resumption** but for that I had to add in the configuration before the build this command: `./configure --enable-all` which "Enables all wolfSSL features, excluding SSL v3".

What is the equivalent command of `--enable-all` I should use in my Cmake configuration ? Or what should I do so I can achieve properly the resumption?

I tried `-DWOLFSSL_ALL` `-DENABLE_ALL` and others but did not managed to do it. I tried including many of them separately to find which is the one that enables the resumption but nothing yet.

Comment: According to the comments in their [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L178), it seems that support for "Enable all" functionality in the CMake project is in TODO list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific wolfSSL option for enabling TLS sessions is `HAVE_SESSION_TICKET`.

There is not currently an equivalent macro for the `./configure --enable-all` option, but you can use the "user_settings" method to get close:
https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/tree/master/examples/configs

Here is an example that configures most of the library options:
https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/master/examples/configs/user_settings_all.h